# Android OutOfMemory Error on Bitmap Creation

Tags: android, memory, graphics, graph, bitmap

I am getting the error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`.

This occurs when creating a bitmap for the purpose of manually drawing a line graph.

```
width = display.getWidth() - 10;
height = width * 4 / 5;
Bitmap emptyBmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
Bitmap charty = createMyGraphAndStuff(emptyBmap);
```

It looks like the total memory allocated was about 700 Kb, an unreasonable amount.

I've seen other solutions invoked when creating bitmaps from a file, but here I am generating one myself. How can I minimize its memory footprint?

***Here's some more code to give you a better idea of what it's doing:***

```
public Bitmap DrawTheGraphAndStuff(Bitmap bitmap, String[] scores)
{
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        drawTheGridLines(canvas);                                   

        plotTheDataPoints(canvas ,  scores ,  "the title" , 0 );    

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
}
```

Comment: why don't you post your "createMyGraphAndStuff(Bitmap b)" function. btw lol at the name!

Comment: can you pasted your `createMyGraphAndStuff` code?

Comment: whats in     createMyGraphAndStuff    ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when the OOM occur, give some advice:

1.need know the oom occur position, the log information is enough

2.the most time is the bitmap process, so you need know how much a image about used memory:

the formula: `w * h * every pixel token memory in byte`, if the `Config` is `Config.ARGB_8888`, every pixel token memory is `4bytes`, if it is the `Config.RGB_565`, is `2bytes`.

3.also, you need know the every app memory limits in your device:

```
   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   activityManager.getMemoryClass(); //return the memory size limit in MB
```

3.if the bitmap did not used again, try `recyle()` it

4.if began the bitmap process, the memory is almost the max memory limit, so use the `adb shell dumpsys meminfo $pid` to check the memory usage, also the `ddms - allocation tracker` is useful

Answer (score 1):

If your display width is 480, your bitmap is 470x376. At 4 bytes per pixel that is 706880 bytes. The only way to use less memory is to make the bitmap smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Basically recycle your bitmaps and you shouldn't have that problem any more. Use recycle().

Comment: good point, after you pass emptyBmap to createMyGraphAndStuff() you can recycle that one since java passes objects by copy instead of a pointer.

Comment: so emptyBmap.recycle() would take care of it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a problem to fix, it's a design issue to address. You cannot assume anything about the heap that will be made available to you. Here are some things that might help you.

- One thing you might want to consider seriously is loading a compressed version of the Bitmap: Figure out the amount of memory available on the heap before loading the Bitmap. Based on this, compute the size of the Bitmap that you want to load, compute the height and width from this and then load the Bitmap.
- **Make sure you are not leaking Bitmaps**. This is one of the major issues people run into. This might happen in a multitude of ways, up from leaking Views to leaking Activities. To check this out, **profile your working memory**.
- When there are no memory leaks, the GC automatically cleans up the Bitmaps. In pre-3.0 devices, you have to invoke recycle() because the GC doesn't do a good job. This is not required in post-3.0 devices. Though be careful, if you invoke recycle() on a Bitmap thats being used, say in an ImageView, you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using soft referenced bitmaps however they may get garbage collected faster than you need them to be.