# Error when load image - "Bitmap size exceeds VM budget"

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this error and the error point to this code:

> bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pic1 , 0, pic1.length);

the picture is from the sqlite database, stored after user select the picture from directory in phone.
when i want to retrieve the picture, i got the error.
from my reading, it is because the memory leak.
Any suggestion/solution?

**Update**

The problem solve when I add the code below before save the image into database.

> BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>
> opt.inSampleSize = 8;
>
> bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,opt);

Thanks for those who reply/answer :)

Comment: try read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904493/android-outofmemory-error-on-bitmap-creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgpath, opt);
```

Comment: Thanks Raghu.Can you explain a bit about this part:
>opt.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

Comment: inTempStorage will allocate some temporal memory for decoding

Answer (score 0):

It could be from a memory leak but it could be that you are just using too much memory. Large images can eat up memory easily. Try to scale the image down if you are having problems and see if you still run into these errors. Try using a memory profiler tool to look for possible leaks.

Comment: Thanks Bobbake4.can you explain about memory profiler tool?how to trace th possible leaks?